# Multiline JLabel using HTML tags and alignment issues

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have `Jlabels` in `JSsrollPane` which are aligned to right. I want the Labels to be multi-lined, so I add `<html>hello<br>world<html>`. Now the problem is that the label no longer aligns to the right instead it fills the whole layout.

How it looks without html tags.

[image]

How it looks with html tags

[image]

MRE:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    static JScrollPane scroll_area = new JScrollPane();
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    static JButton btn = new JButton("Add");

    private static final Color lbl_color = new Color(171, 171, 171);
    private static final EmptyBorder lbl_padding = new EmptyBorder(10, 10,10, 10);


    Test(){
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        scroll_area.getViewport().add(panel);
        scroll_area.createVerticalScrollBar();
        scroll_area.createHorizontalScrollBar();

        add(scroll_area);
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(e -> addText());

        setSize(300, 30);

    }

    public static void addText(){
        String text = "<html><font color='#F9F6F6'>Hello world <br> Welcome to Earth</font></html>";
//        String text = "Hello world Welcome to Earth";

        JLabel mess_lbl = new JLabel(text, JLabel.RIGHT);

        mess_lbl.setOpaque(true);
        mess_lbl.setBackground(lbl_color);
        mess_lbl.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        panel.add(mess_lbl);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        panel.updateUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        frame.add(new Test());
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

I would like my multi-lined labels to the right side of the layout as shown in image1.

Comment: `<p align='right'>...</p>` ... My HTML is massively rusty though

Comment: @MadProgrammer it looks like it aligns the text to right, not the label. I don't want  the 
 Label to not fill the whole layout (it should look like the label in image 1)

Comment: i think we can not do anything about it.

Comment: That looks more like an issue with `BoxLayout`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there something I can do to get the correct alignment? any recommendations?

Comment: Use a different layout manager?

Comment: @JacksonPro You use a vertical BoxLayout that allows component expands horizontally to it's maximum size; JLabel with plain text has max size = preferred size, while JLabel with html has max size on X axis = Integer.MAX_VALUE, just change layout manager

Comment: @user15358848 .. or not. See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with `BoxLayout`, so you might want to wait and see if someone else has any ideas or suggestions.  But with just a little bit of effort I was able to get it to work using a `GridBagLayout` instead

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    static JScrollPane scroll_area = new JScrollPane();
    static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    static JButton btn = new JButton("Add");

    private static final Color lbl_color = new Color(171, 171, 171);
    private static final EmptyBorder lbl_padding = new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);

    private JPanel filler = new JPanel();

    Test() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);
        gbc.weighty = 1;

        panel.add(filler, gbc);

        scroll_area.getViewport().add(panel);
        scroll_area.createVerticalScrollBar();
        scroll_area.createHorizontalScrollBar();

        add(scroll_area);
        add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(e -> addText());

        setSize(300, 30);

    }

    private int counter;

    public void addText() {
        counter += 1;
        String text = "<html><font color='#F9F6F6'>Hello world <br> Welcome to Earth " + counter + "</font></html>";
//        String text = "Hello world Welcome to Earth";

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);

        JLabel mess_lbl = new JLabel(text, JLabel.RIGHT);

        mess_lbl.setOpaque(true);
        mess_lbl.setBackground(lbl_color);
        mess_lbl.setAlignmentX(Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        panel.add(mess_lbl, gbc, panel.getComponentCount() - 1);

        //panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)));
        panel.revalidate();
        panel.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        frame.add(new Test());
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```